# Proof for an integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, integral-inequality

For a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $|f|\leq M$, $f(s)\equiv 0$ for $s<0$, define
\begin{equation}
I^n(t)= n \int_{t-1/n}^{t} f(s)ds.
\end{equation}
In my book they conclude that
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
|I^n(t')-I^n(t)|\leq 2n|t'-t|M.
\end{equation}

How can I proof this inequality? I only see that
\begin{equation}
|I^n(t')-I^n(t)|\leq |n[(t'-t'+1/n)M-(t-t+1/n)M]|=0.
\end{equation}

Comment: It should be $2M|t'-t|$ I think.

Comment: Do we have any conditions on $t$ and $t'$?  Are they just *any* real numbers?

Comment: Also, what you've shown is wrong, because you've bounded $f$ by $M$ but actually we have $|f| \leq M$.  So you don't have $0$ as a bound.  Do you see why?

Comment: If the ranges of integration overlap, the difference between the integrals is bounded by stuff that depends on the 2 non-overlapping parts of the ranges.  This is what happens when $|t-t'|< 1/n$. The two parts are of length  $|t-t'|$ each, and the integrand is bounded by $M$.  (By the way, you left of a factor of $n$ in your formula for $I^n$.)

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. I forgot the factor of n before the integral. t and t' are just any two real numbers. How do you get this result, zhw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $I^n(t)=\int_{t-1/n}^{t} f(s) \,ds$ and $I^n(t')=\int_{t'-1/n}^{t'} f(s)\,ds$.

Then 
\begin{split}|I^n(t) - I^n(t')| &= n|\int_{t-\frac{1}{n}}^{t} f(s) \,ds - \int_{t'-\frac{1}{n}}^{t'} f(s)\,ds| \\ &\leq n\left(|\int_{t-\frac{1}{n}}^{t} f(s) \,ds| + |\int_{t'-\frac{1}{n}}^{t'} f(s)\,ds| \right) \\ &= n\left( |\int_{t-\frac{1}{n}}^{t} f(s) \,ds| + |\int_{t'}^{t'-\frac{1}{n}} f(s)\,ds| \right) \\&\leq nM(t - (t - \frac{1}{n}) + nM(t'  - \frac{1}{n} - t') \\ &=nM(t - t') + nM(t' - t) \\&\leq 2Mn|t-t'|  \end{split}

Comment: I forgot the factor of n before the integral, sorry for this. But that does not change much for your calcluations. Unfortunately I don´t see how I can get the correct estimate from this as $2M(n|t-t'|+1)$ is greater than $2Mn|t-t'|$.

Comment: @Spike Which book is it?  And what page is it on?  I'd like to take a look.

Comment: Page 4 (Step two): https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec15.pdf

Comment: @Spike I figured it out and modified my answer above.  The key is that since $\int \limits_{a}^{b} f(s)\,ds = -\int \limits_{b}^{a} f(s)\,ds$, we have $\left |\int \limits_{t' - \frac{1}{n}}^{t'} f(s) \,ds \right | =  \left |\int \limits_{t'}^{t' - \frac{1}{n}} f(s) \,ds \right |$.  This allows the term with $\frac{1}{n}$ to cancel with the other $\frac{1}{n}$ term since they will have opposite signs, as above.  I hope that helps!

Comment: That's it, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put $u=t-s $.
then
$$I^n (t)=\int_0^\frac 1nf (t-u)du $$

and

$$I^n (t)-I^n (t')=\int_0^\frac 1n (f (t-u)-f (t'-u))du $$

Comment: Doing some estimates I get $|n\int_{0}^{1/n}f(t-u)-f(t'-u)du|\leq n\int_{0}^{1/n}|f(t-u)|+|f(t'-u)|du\leq 2M$. But not the result I want to show. How would you continue your estimate?